# Spacing between columns when printing issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem when printing in chrome

The space between tow boxes is not shown

```
<style>
    .textstyle2
    {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-5 text-left textstyle2">
    <p>Text</p>
    <br />
    <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5 col-md-offset-2 text-right textstyle2">
    <p class="text-left">Text</p>
    <br />
    <p class="text-left">Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: [See DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu85g8rL/8/)

```
.textstyle2
{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

Comment: thanks how can i move the second box to the end of the page

Comment: What do you mean by end of the page ? To right side ?

Comment: you have to use `float:right;` for the second box, and maybe adding a right margin to it

Comment: @Ayman, as you are using `bootstrap`, just replace the class `text-right` by `pull-right`.